# How can I open my html file on Google Chrome?

Tags: html, visual-studio, google-chrome, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to get used to html. I want open my html project on Google Chrome but I am just getting classic page on local host. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFJDg.jpg) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZjuK.jpg)

I am just try to open on Edge but get this page again. What can I do about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just paste the path of the html file including the .html to the browser.
Eg, c://Desktop/user/project/file.html -> paste on url

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways for opening .html files in Google chrome.

Way 1 :

Right click on the .html file and select open with Google chrome.

Way 2 :

1. Open Google Chrome
2. Press ctrl + o
3. A window opens
4. Navigate to your destination folder and click on your .html file

That's it. There you go.

Hope This is helpful.